# Docusign Formatting and Salesforce integration issue

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am in a Salesforce environment and trying to send out a docusign document using Docusign and Conga.  I am using a 30 day trial.

1.Using Conga and Docusign works very well together and the formatting is correct except that I need to have 2 radio buttons on the form.  Is there a way to add anchor tags to my Word document and hide them(white text) like I do for the Docusign signature and date tags?

I tried following the documentation for creating the radio buttons in Docusign and tie them to a picklist field in Salesforce but I have yet been able to write back to Salesforce.

2. How do you control the text length for a Docusign template?  I have fields that make up the address but the spacing is not dynamic so depending on the field value the text may run into each other.  Is there a way to have the fields adjust based on field value length?
3. How do I show multiple related records?  I have a case with multiple activities associated to it and I need to display them.  In Conga I use a table and all of the records show.  But if I create a docusign template it is only showing the first record.

If at all possible I would prefer to add the anchor tags to the existing document since the formatting is cleaner.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

1. There is. You'll want to avoid applying anchor tags directly to a DocuSign template when working in the web console. The reason for this is that when you're sending from Salesforce with or without Salesforce anchor strings you're going to receive an error message indicating that there's no text associated with an anchor string.

You can accomplish this through Custom Fields inside of Salesforce.
Basically, you place your text in white where you want the tag to attach to your document. You'll want to set the anchor string in the format of \variable{r}\ on the tag, then in the underlying document you would replace {r} with the recipient number in the signing order.

IE: \variable_{r}\ becomes \variable_1\, when Salesforce picks this up it will tag the document automatically. For more information, see here: https://support.docusign.com/guides/dfs-user-guide-use-automatic-anchor-text-with-custom-tags-user.

2. In terms of writing back the value of a Radio Button, as I'm sure you've noticed this can be tricky. The values for the picklist in Salesforce need to match up exactly, then be written back by adding a new line in your Connect object. A step by step guide is available on the support site: https://support.docusign.com/articles/DocuSign-for-Salesforce-How-to-update-a-Salesforce-Field-with-a-DocuSign-Radio-Button-Value.
3. The Width of a text field is determined in one of a few ways: 
   1) You can supply a fixed size in the API call being used to generate them.
   2) You can save the custom field inside of DocuSign as a Custom Field after setting the width to it.
   3) Set the Fixed Size flag to false, then the text field should fill itself out when text is applied to it.
4. Would you mind being more specific in regards to the status record?

Comment: Matt, thank for the reply. I think I have everything except for the righting back to Salesforce. Based on the instructions if I have 2 radio button how does Docusign know what value to send back to the picklist?  I am assuming the tooltip value in the radio button is supposed to match the picklist value in Salesforce?  Not for sure what you are referencing in point 4 above.  Thanks

Comment: Michael, the picklist values on the Salesforce end need to be locked, and the values for the Radio Buttons need to be set to have the same values. The Radio Buttons have a specific value for each item in the group when selected. It also looks like someone on the support site came up with a clever alternative you may want to consider trying: https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00009756

Comment: Hey Matt,
I am not sure by what you mean when you say 'Locked'.  And to confirm the values in the radio button that should be entered where?  In the tooltip section?  
Thanks again,
Michael

Comment: Matt, I used the alternative option you listed and this worked. Thanks